# How to rehang a door by myself?

Tags: home, hardware

#### I have a door. It fell down.

How can I rehang it by myself? More specifically, how can I hold it up, a few inches off the ground, while screwing in the hinges?

Comment: Shouldn't be asked at [Home Improvements SE](http://diy.stackexchange.com/)? There are few similar.

Comment: @kenorb It could be asked there, but 1) Lifehacks doesn't have an exclusive topic, and 2) I'm looking for "a better mousetrap", so to speak. A substitute tool, really.

Comment: Did just the door fall down, or was it the whole door frame?

Comment: @adam Just the door itself.

Comment: Flagged to close as not needing a life hack. Hanging a door is a DIY how-to. Holding things a few inches off the ground requires a thing that is a few inches thick, not a hack.

Answer (score 3):

There are plenty of advice available on Internet (for instance, examples [here](http://home-building.wonderhowto.com/how-to/hang-door-216840/) and [here](http://www.thisoldhouse.com/toh/how-to/step/0,,20407803,00.html)).

In addition to the tips mentioned there, I would just add a few:

- If there is another person available to help, that would be excellent.
- Use [anchors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wall_plug) in the screw holes, if the screw holes are not damaged.
- If possible, use slightly longer screws. For example, use 1.25 inches, if 1 inch screws were used previously.
  *You need to use caution not to use a screw which will pass through the door frame, or damage it or the wall.*
- Place small wooden pieces underneath the door so it would can be leveled easily with the hinges. Holding the door may not result in best results.

Good Luck.

Comment: "If there is another person available to help, that would be excellent." <= That's my biggest problem!

Answer (score 2):

Take three pieces of 1x4 about a foot long and ripped one piece a little larger than the width/depth of the door (about 1 1/2in).  Then nailed them together to form a U shape with the ripped piece at the bottom of the U.

This setup gives some support to keep the door vertical while attaching to the frame.

Comment: Preferably a solution with less materials. This isn't very hacky.

Answer (score 2):

If you already know where the hinges need to be attached then you could remove the hinge pins, separate the hinge, attach the loose half of the hinge to the door frame, then get the door hinges lined up with the door frame hinges and put the pins back in.